# can not run node js project in version 8

Tags: node.js, asp.net-mvc-4

i am trying to node js project run in visual studio 2015 but if i used node version 6 then project is run but i trying to version 8 then show the following error.

error:-

```
(node:6600) [DEP0062] DeprecationWarning: `node --debug` and `node --debug-brk` are invalid. Please use `node --inspect` or `node --inspect-brk` instead.
```

server.js:-

```
var http = require('http');
var port = process.env.port || 1337;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
   res.end('Hello World\n');

}).listen(port);
```

Comment: delete /clear out  the node_modules  folder and `npm install` to download the package compact able for the version  ( which is now changed to 8) then try running the app again

Comment: If VSCode is used, refer to [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/27731#issuecomment-305265014) and [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32529). Also worth to read [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/44371).

Comment: @JoelJoseph you delete then npm install but already install in npm and version 8.14.1

Comment: you means new version npm install right

Comment: @JoelJoseph not working sir...

Answer (score 0):

Install visual studio 2017 then working on node js 8 version...